# How to stop Google Chrome from removing ../ from the requested URL?

Tags: google-chrome, path-traversal

I'm testing if my application is prone to path traversal attacks, but when browsing  to localhost/browser/../123/456.txt Chrome automatically converts the URL to localhost/browser/123/456.txt. How can I prevent Google Chrome from removing the ../ part?

Comment: I doubt Google will alter Chrome for you, but there are other tools available - you could try [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL).

Comment: I used curl with the --path-as-is flag to test out my application. Thanks for the hint.